# How should i model a ranking based on age values? (in Java)

Tags: java, class, modeling, ranking

My aim is to get a player ranking depending on score/points and age.
I have a list of player entries in a csv file like the followoing:

Name;Stat;Rang;AK;IDNR;Nat;Vbd;Verein;PKT

Aarts,   Stefan;-;0;M35;17901189;NED;TVN;TC   Kaiserswerth;400,0

Abe,   Peter;A;0;M75;14000158;GER;TVN;TC   Am   Volkswald;282,0

You see column 4 contains the age (AK). I want to create a ranking for each different AK, based on the column "PKT" (is points).

I thought about something like a dictionary with the value of AK as key and in the value the array filled with each player which has this value in column AK. So I can use the sort method of class Array.

On the other hand I could create a class playerEntry with all those columns as attributes. But then sorting by age group AK is more difficult I think.

There is an additional requirement: If a player has status 'A' he gets a ranking but he is not counted (foreigners do not count for national ranking) in the total list.

At the end the result shall look similar to this small table:

```
Name           Stat Rang    AK  IDNR     Nat    Vbd Verein               PKT
Brown, Dustin   -   3     M30   18404206    GER TVN Gladbacher HTC   9848
Kohlschreiber, Philipp  -   1   M30 18304168    GER TVM TK Kurhaus Aachen   9848
Becker, Benjamin    -   2   M30 18108797    GER BAD TK GW Mannheim  8733
Mertl, Jan      A   4   M30 18201757    CZE TTV Erfurter TC Rot-Wei 8650
Ghem, Andre     A   4   M30 18250664    BRA TVN Ratinger TC GW      4777
Mayer, Florian  -   4   M30 18303368    GER TVM TK Kurhaus Aachen   4763
```

You see that foreign players like Mertl and GHem have an identic rank and Mayer has the same rank although he has less points.

Any suggestions, what would be the better way?
After sorting I will have to add the ranking but this will be easy. ;-)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please refer to [ask] page to help you formulate a better question.  At minimum, you should be able to show some research of your own, some attempt at solving the problem and where you are stuck.  All you have right now is a set of requirements and the hope that someone will do the work for you (and this is not how SO works).. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In your PlayerEntry class, implement java.lang.Comparable interface, and provide an implementation for the compareTo() method as described [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2014/02/java-comparable-example-for-natural-order-sorting.html).

Within compareTo(), your would simply compare each player entry instance on age group.

Comment: Sounds valid, but I have no idea how to compare players with different age groups.
I will provide an adiitional example for that...

Comment: I did it like that:  

    PlayerEntry haas = new PlayerEntry("Tommy Haas", "M35", 7000);  
    PlayerEntry haas2 = new PlayerEntry("Tommy Haas2", "M35", 7001);  

    class PlayerEntry implements Comparable<PlayerEntry> {  
 private String name;  
 private String ak;  
 private int points;  
  
 public PlayerEntry(String name, String ak, int points) {  
  this.name = name;  
  this.ak = ak;   
  this.points = points;  
 }  

 @Override  
 public int compareTo(PlayerEntry player) {  
  return this.points - player.points;   
 }    

I have no idea to sort with ak and the points within ak.

Comment: Your compareTo method could be as simple as this: `    @Override 
    public int compareTo(PlayerEntry otherPlayer) { 
        
        if (this.getAk() != null)
        {
            return this.getAk().compareTo(otherPlayer.getAk());
        }
        return -1;
    }`  See this link for an example: [link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10)  Sorting is the easy part - use a TreeSet or other ordered collection, and the PlayerEntries will sort themselves.

Comment: But this will only sort for AKs, not for points in AKs.

I thought a little bit about it.
Coding like:
if (this.AK.equals(otherPlayer.getAK()) {  
then return this.points-otherPlayer.getPoints();
}
else return this.AK.hashCode() - otherPlayer.getAK().hashCode();

will solve it I think, This sorts first for AK, then for points. So in the AK all entries are sorted for points.